# Email attachments to unique recipients based on attachment name

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, pdf

Good day, 
I am an absolute newbie at using any form of scripting or programing so please forgive me if I don't provide enough information or context.

I need to email around 1000 PDF documents a day to various recipients.

We receive a request with a unique 9 digit reference number. 
Each request is logged in a table which details the requestors email address and the reference number generated. 
We then process the order and save the invoice with the same 9 digit reference number as a pdf.
I then need to open outlook, 
attach the relevant document (named with the reference number), 
add the relevant email address in the To: field, from the table.
Copy and paste a standard worded message and send to the client.

Doing this manually ofcourse takes time, and in some instances results in errors, 
eg. reference number 1 gets sent to the wrong receipient.

we cannot add any new programs other than outlook to handle the process.
Any and all advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just using mailto link to setup the subject line?  Without the ability to add programs what you want likely isn't possible with your level of permissions.

Comment: That does work but still requires me or the user to manually enter in the email address. thats kinda where it goes a bit pear shaped. one user emailed invoices to a clients competitor showing their preferential discounts. you can imagine the outcome :)

Comment: @Ramhound If i were to get admin rights etc, what could i do to make this happen?

Comment: You can use something like Excel to cancatenate different cells to generate a link easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like the need for a bit of programming.

It could quite easily be solved with VBA in Access or even in Excel.
It's not very complex but maybe not a job for an absolute newbie.

Comment: I have nothing to lose so am willing to try anything. Let me know what can be done. i have done a bit of VBA in excel before so think i could manage.